# How to check if a sequence's subsequences (trigrams) are random using a Monte Carlo experiment?

Tags: monte-carlo, random-generation

Let's say I have a process that produces sequences.

I might have another process (or processes) that will add their own output to the data sequences at random points. 
To check if a subsequence (any 3 subsequent tokens in a sequence) is the product of the primary process alone or whether secondary processes are involved, I decided to use a Monte Carlo experiment.

First, I counted the frequency of each trigram in the sequences I have.
Then, I randomized their order (also across sequences), and counted again the frequency of each trigram. I randomized, counted and summarized the results thusly for 1000 iterations.

How should I compare trigram counts between the real data and the randomized sequences to see whether a trigram is likely to be the output of the primary process or the combination of the primary and secondary process(es)?